# Where do I get make for cygwin?

Tags: c++, cygwin, make

I need binary file.

Answer (score 39):

Use the CYGWIN installer from

- http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe (32-bit installer)
- http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe (64-bit installer)

and select the **make** package from the Devel group during installation.

Comment: good thing is that installing doesn't seem to overwrite previous stuff you had. I have done a reinstallation and my files remained intact

Comment: That installer is actually an installer-cum-updater. So you don't need to worry about loosing previous packages.

Answer (score 15):

You can install it from the Cygwin `setup.exe` install program.  When you get to the "Select Packages" screen, expand the "Devel" section, find the `make` package, and select the version you want by clicking the weird circle/arrow thing on that line until your desired version is shown.

Comment: More concise answer as compared to the other answer, +1!